# Why json output so small?

Tags: python, json, api, rest

This output should be way longer than it is in here.

I start with a GET request, I parse a JSON list and extract the id, which I then call on the second function, that will give me a second ID which then I will use to call on the 3rd function. But, I am only getting one entry whereas I should be getting way more entries.

The code is the following:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def countries():
    data = requests.get("https://localhost:8543/api/netim/v1/countries/", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
    rep = data.json()
    return [elem.get("id","") for elem in rep['items']]


def regions():
    for c in countries():
        url = requests.get("https://localhost:8543/api/netim/v1/countries/{}/regions".format(c), verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
        response = url.json()
        return [cid.get("id","") for cid in response['items']]


def city():
    for r in regions():
        api = requests.get("https://localhost:8543/api/netim/v1/regions/{}/cities".format(r), verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
        resolt = api.json()
        return(json.dumps([{"name":r.get("name",""),"id":r.get("id", "")} for r in resolt['items']], indent=4))
city()

print(city())
```

The output is the following :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Herat",
        "id": "AF~HER~Herat"
    }
]
```

I should have a huge list, so I am not sure what am I missing?

Comment: Sounds more like a server side issue than a client side one

Comment: you `return` in the first iteration of the loop

Comment: Only the first item returned by `countries()` actually gets processed in `regions()`: you get the response for that one, and then `return`, thus ending the function.  Likewise, `city()` only processes the first item from `regions()`, and then returns.

Comment: @Macattack Thank, i am not sure i understand ? I am not a big programmer so could you clarify please ?

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks Jason, but if i print the result of hte second function i do indeed get all the regions from all the countries. so why isnt the function passing all the id's to the third one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through all the iterations of your loop and collect the results, then jsonify the and return them.

```
data = []
for r in regions():
    api = requests.get("https://localhost:8543/api/netim/v1/regions/{}/cities".format(r), verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
    resolt = api.json()
    data.extend([{"name":r.get("name",""),"id":r.get("id", "")} for r in resolt['items']])
return json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

This would be a fix for `city()` but you have the same problem in all your functions. `return` immediately exits the function and does not do anything else, effectively all your `for` loops are doing 1 iteration.

I'll update my example here to give you a better idea what's occurring.

Your functions are basically this:

```
def test_fn():
    for i in [1,2,3,4]:
        return i
# output:
1
# We never see 2 or 3 or 4 because we return before looping on them.
```

What you want:

```
def test_fn():
    results = []
    for i in [1,2,3,4]:
        results.append(i)
    return results
# output
[1,2,3,4]
```

It seems like you understand that the `for` loop is going to take some action once for each element in the list. What you're not understanding is that `return` ends the function NOW. No more for loop, no more actions, and in your code, you immediately return inside the for loop, stopping any further action.

Comment: Thanks, i understand, but how can i store the above fuctions? i am not sure i understand how to just sore the values i am looking for ?

Comment: @AlexandreAmaralBednell i added more examples, let me know if you don't understand